# Android add watermark to image without out of memory exception

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an application that uploads pictures to Facebook.

I'm using Apache `MultipartEntityBuilder` class for sending those pictures from my phone using the `addPart()` method that loads the image in parts and send each parts alone to the Facebook server, and by that helps me no to get out of memory exception.

I want to add my watermark to the picture before uploading it, but when i'm thinking about this i can think of 2 problems:

1. if i will load the picture to the memory it will probelby cause an out of memory exception.
2. i don't want to scale the image, i want to upload it with the same resolution it was taken, and let Facebook deal with scaling.

What will be the best approach to open this Bitmap, add a watermark, send it multi part to Facebook and do all that without getting out of memory exception ?